# Abstract class declared as final

Tags: java

What if an abstract class defined as final?   I know abstract class meaning , but am not sure how to use that and why it will be declared on the first place?

Comment: What happened when you tried declaring an abstract final class?

Comment: When I tried it the compiler said "Illegal combination of modifiers: abstract and final".  So I'm guessing the OP didn't even do that.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler will not let you declare a class as both `abstract` and `final`.

[Section 8.1.1.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2) states:

> It is a compile-time error if a class is declared both `final` and `abstract`, because the implementation of such a class could never be completed (§8.1.1.1).